# Some problems with loading models in Stanford Neural Network Dependency Parser

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm using the Stanford Neural network Dependency Parser. I've trained some models on French treebanks (GSD, ParTUT, Sequoia, Spoken), and now I'm trying to generate the output of the model on the test segments of the treebanks. It all works fine with ParTUT, Sequoia and Spoken, but GSD gives me some problems. The command I run is:

```
java -Xmx1g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser \ -model Stf_ud_gsd_2200.model.txt.gz.gz -testFile fr_gsd_ud_test_new.conllu -outFile FR/Stf_gsd_ud.conllu
```

I receive the following error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "358,6"
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser.loadModelFile(DependencyParser.java:570)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser.loadModelFile(DependencyParser.java:508)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser.main(DependencyParser.java:1284)
```

If I understand this correctly, the problem does not stem from the test-treebank, but rather from the model itself, and the way some numbers have been saved there.

Does anyone have any tips on how to overcome it? I'd be very grateful for help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the French GSD training data there is space containing token.
`3 358,6`.  So when the model loading code reads in the embedding for that token, it splits on space, and thinks the first value of the embedding is `358,6`.

If you add a comma into that token (by editing that one line) your model will work.
I think you can just remove that line and decrease the dictionary size specified at the top by 1 (to reflect one less word in the vocabulary).

We should fix this issue though in the training code, usually tokens don't have space in them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try that!